# Summing Binomial Expansion

Tags: education, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I am trying to understand the formula for the sum of `n` positive integers from [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/). I understand how the binomial part works.

For the expansion of $(k-1)^2$:

$(k−1)^2 = k^2 − 2k + 1$

Rearrange the terms as below:

$k^2−(k−1)^2=2k−1$

Now sum both sides:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2−(k−1)^2) = 2\sum_{k=1}^nk-\sum_{k=1}^n1$$

Problem and my question starts from here, Can anyone please add in simple words with simple equation/calculation how below results come:

It equals $n^2$.The right side equals $2S_n$$ - n$, which gives $2S_n$$-n$=$n^2$,so $S_n$ = $\frac{n(n+1)}2$.

Comment: The terms of the left cancel $1^2-0^2+2^2-1^2+...+n^2-(n-1)^2$. That's all that happens.

Comment: why we subtracting $0^2$ ?

Comment: $(k^2-(k-1)^2)$ for $k=1$ becomes $1^2-0^2$.

Comment: so it should be $n^2 - (n-1)^2$ why only $n^2$?

Comment: The last term, for $k=n$ is $n^2-(n-1)^2$, but before it there is the term $(n-1)^2-(n-2)^2$, which is for $k=n-1$. So, the $(n-1)^2$ is also getting cancelled.

Comment: So, all terms cancel except the $n^2$ and the $-0^2$.

Comment: Thank you. any help for right-hand side? and can you post it as answer

Comment: The right side has a $2$ multiplying the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$, which is the sum that you are computing, and it has $\sum_{k=1}^{n}1$, which is $1$ added to itself $n$ times, one for each of the possible values of $k=1,2,3,...,n$.